# SQL Write Alias to permanent column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write the result of this SELECT to a permanent column, instead of a alias. Using MySQL.

```
SELECT Machine_1_AccProduction,
     Machine_1_AccProduction - coalesce(lag(Machine_1_AccProduction) OVER (order by Time_Stamp), 0) AS diff
from dobbelttapper_1.dobbelttapper_1_accproduction;
```

I have tried to use a Update statement, but get the error "Operand should contain 1 column".

```
UPDATE dobbelttapper_1.dobbelttapper_1_accproduction
SET diff = 
             (SELECT Machine_1_AccProduction,
     Machine_1_AccProduction - coalesce(lag(Machine_1_AccProduction) OVER (order by Time_Stamp), 0) AS diff
FROM dobbelttapper_1.dobbelttapper_1_accproduction);
```

From Stu´s comment I reduced the Query to this:

```
UPDATE dobbelttapper_1.dobbelttapper_1_accproduction
SET diff = 
(SELECT Machine_1_AccProduction - coalesce(lag(Machine_1_AccProduction) OVER (order by Time_Stamp), 0));
```

Now the update works fine, but the result is just a repeat of  Machine_1_AccProduction?

This is the result I get:

```
      Time_Stamp      |Machine_1_AccProduction|  diff
'2021-04-11 20:40:48', '130859',                '130859'
'2021-04-11 20:40:53', '130859',                '130859'
'2021-04-11 20:40:58', '130862',                '130862'
'2021-04-11 20:41:03', '130864',                '130864'
'2021-04-11 20:41:08', '130865',                '130865'
'2021-04-11 20:41:13', '130867',                '130867'
'2021-04-11 20:41:18', '130870',                '130870'
```

This is what I would like to get:

```
      Time_Stamp      |Machine_1_AccProduction|  diff
'2021-04-11 20:40:48', '130859',                '0'
'2021-04-11 20:40:53', '130859',                '0'
'2021-04-11 20:40:58', '130862',                '3'
'2021-04-11 20:41:03', '130864',                '2'
'2021-04-11 20:41:08', '130865',                '1'
'2021-04-11 20:41:13', '130867',                '2'
'2021-04-11 20:41:18', '130870',                '3'
```

Comment: please tag your RDBMS. The error tells you everything you need to know, you are updating a column to the value returned by your sub-select, which is returning 2 columns. Remove the first column.

Comment: Thanks, now the update works fine. But the result is just a repeat of the Machine_1_AccProduction column.

Comment: We have no idea what is in your table. You are updating all rows for `diff` to be the same value and that value will be a random value from your `select`, which could be the same because you are subtracting `0` in the event the `lag` returns `null`. Share sample data and expected output to make it easier to help you.

Comment: No of course, my mistake. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LAG()` in an `UPDATE` is quite tricky in MySQL.  Basically, it requires running the query and then joining back on a primary key or unique key.  Let me assume that time stamp is unique:

```
UPDATE dobbelttapper_1.dobbelttapper_1_accproduction ap JOIN
       (SELECT ap2.*,
               LAG(ap2.Machine_1_AccProduction, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Time_Stamp) as prev_Machine_1_AccProduction
        FROM dobbelttapper_1.dobbelttapper_1_accproduction ap2
       ) ap2
       ON ap.time_stamp = ap2.time_stamp
    SET ap.diff = ap.Machine_1_AccProduction - ap2.prev_Machine_1_AccProduction;
```